# Can I use SO-DIMM instead of DIMM?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I've bought a Sapphire PURE White E350 (IPC-E350M1W) Mainboard probably the wrong RAM: Corsair Memory — 4GB DDR3 SODIMM Memory (CMSO4GX3M1A1333C9)

Can I use the SODIMM RAM with this mainboard or do I have to send it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's laptop RAM (204-pin) vs. Desktop RAM (240-pin).  You have the lappy RAM, which does you no good on a board for desktop.  Be sure you get 240-pin DDR3.

It won't even fit in the slots.  So send it back.